# when uploading file 0 error is coming in php

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I am uploading an image in PHP.Image is of **.jpg** type but when uploading it, it is giving me error **0**.

This is my code.

```
if(isset($_FILES["image_file"]["name"])){
    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["image_file"]["name"]));
    if ((($_FILES["image_file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["image_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["image_file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["image_file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["image_file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["image_file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    //&& ($_FILES["image_file"]["size"] < $size)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
      {
      if ($_FILES["image_file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["image_file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
      else
        {
            $generate_random_number = rand(1,1000);
            $random_image_name = $generate_random_number.$_FILES["image_file"]["name"];
          if (file_exists($upload_dir_path.$random_image_name))
              {
                //echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
              }
          else
          {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image_file"]["tmp_name"],
            $upload_dir_path.$random_image_name);
          }
        }
      }
    else
      {print_r($_FILES);
        echo "Invalid file";
      }

}
```

When running the following is the output:

`Array ( [image_file] => Array ( [name] => Chambers_block_study.JPG [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpghmfM2 [error] => 0 [size] => 2656165 ) )`

Invalid file

Please help.Thanks!

Comment: That looks okay, doesn't it? Error 0 = no error.

Comment: What you're expecting ? Isn't it cool if your file is getting uploaded without any error ?

Comment: I think Ravi is expecting that to output when there is an error, but it looks like the conditions are not correct so that will output when all is ok.

Comment: @Rikesh file is not uploading.

Comment: How do you know that, what happens? There clearly is a file in the tmp directory and it has a size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Error 0 means no error,](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) so everything should be okay. If you are having a problem, it is not caused by the file upload itself.

Side note: to detect a JPG image, better use [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/getimagesize) instead of checking for extensions / MIME types. Those are set by the client and can be forged.

Example:

```
$info = getimagesize($_FILES["image_file"]["tmp_name"]);

if ($info == false) 
 {
 echo "Image is not a valid image file";
 // do whatever
 }
```

Comment: the main thing is not for checking type. error is coming so file is not uploading.

Comment: I got the error. error was of case sensitive.I used array with jpg while file is of JPG so error was coming.Thanks

Comment: @Ravi okay, but as said, that's not a very good method to check for whether it's an image.

Answer (score 1):

maybe because it's case sensitive: you have `jpg` in your array, but files ends with `JPG`
try

```
in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight from by the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php):

```
UPLOAD_ERR_OK
Value: 0; There is no error, the file uploaded with success.
```

Which means your file was uploaded correctly.

If the user uploads a file with .JPG extension, your if statement will fail. So I'd rather use something like this for checking the image extension:

```
$image_ext =  strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES["image_file"]["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

Also, it's better to use [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/getimagesize) for checking the validity of an image. You can use it as follows:

```
$isImageValid = @getimagesize($image_tmp);
if($isImageValid){
//do whatever
}
```

Hope this helps!